# How to use user-defined scalar inside datatable creation in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Basically I'd like to define a scalar and then use that scalar inside of a datatable. Something like:

```
let dayOne = "Day One";
let dayTwo = "Day Two";
let dayStringMapping = datatable(Batch: int64, BatchDay: string)
    [   
    01, dayOne,
    02, dayTwo
    ];
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `datatable` operator requires constant scalar values as its input.

An alternative approach could be using the `print` operator.

If required, you can `union` several rows generated by multiple usages of the `print` operator.

For example:

```
let dayOne = "Day One";
let dayTwo = "Day Two";
let dayStringMapping = 
    union (print Batch = 1, BatchDay = dayOne),
          (print Batch = 2, BatchDay = dayTwo);
... do something with 'dayStringMapping' ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response-- unfortunately from the docs, `print` returns a single row, whereas (sorry this wasn't clear in my question) I am using a multi-row table. I'll update my example to reflect this.

Comment: This worked, thanks so much! (needed a comma after the first row in case you wanted to update that)